# how to fill numbers in Triangle multidimensional arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, while-loop

how to fill numbers in these arrays?

```
[ 
 [ 0 ], 
 [ 0, 0 ], 
 [ 0, 0, 0 ], 
 [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ] 
]
```

what i got for nested loops, the numbers i fill is same like the numbers of target(num) ; it repeats numbers target(num) in those arrays

looks below:

```js
var arr = [
  [0],
  [0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0]
]
var num = 20

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
    for (var k = 0; k <= num; k++) {
      arr[i][j] = k
    }
  }
};
console.log(arr)
```

the output i want is like this :

```
[ 
 [ 1 ], 
 [ 3, 5 ], 
 [ 7, 9, 11 ], 
 [ 13, 15, 17, 19 ] 
]
```

can anyone explain why my codes repeat the same number ? unlike the output i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the innermost loop, you're reassigning `arr[i][j] = k` over and over again, until `k` reaches 20. So, every time the innermost loop is reached, `arr[i][j]` becomes 20.

You only need 2 loops: an outer (loop over `arr`) and an inner one (loop over each subarray), while keeping a persistent counter outside:

```js
var arr = [
  [0],
  [0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0]
];

var counter = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
    arr[i][j] = counter;
    counter++;
  }
}
console.log(arr);
```

(also note that a `for` loop's `}` should not have a `;` after it)

To display only odd numbers:

```js
var arr = [
  [0],
  [0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0]
];

var counter = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
    arr[i][j] = counter;
    counter += 2;
  }
}
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: could we write condition in those nested loop? if the counter odd, or even, we fill the arr with those odd number /even? @CertainPerformance

Comment: how about if. the target. the counter I want till 20? so if the counter % 2 === 1 ? the odd numbers should on that array , it gonna be 1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19  in the Triangle .array?

Comment: Just do `counter += 2` instead of `counter++` to add 2 instead of 1

Comment: i tried, but it return like the same arr, look https://repl.it/repls/JuvenileShabbyCarriers

Comment: You added an extra line that isn't in my answer. `if(counter % 2 == 1) {` Remove that block and just change the code in my answer from `counter++` to `counter += 2`

Comment: it is still the same result

Comment: ohh the counter from 1, i see, thank you, that is what i am looking for, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a variable to keep track of value to be inserted and map

```js
var arr = [[ 0 ],[ 0, 0 ],[ 0, 0, 0 ],[ 0, 0, 0, 0 ]]

let value = 0;

let op= arr.map(e=>{
  return e.map(el=> el=++value)
})
console.log(op)
```

Comment: i update my output, i want the odd number on those arr from 20

Comment: @ZumDummi just change `value=0` to `value=1` and `el=++value` to `{value+=2; return el=value:}`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [
  [0],
  [0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0]
]
var num = 20

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
    for (var k = 0; k <= num; k++) {
      arr[i][j] = k
    }
  }
};
console.log(arr)
```

The third **for loop** always executing code 20 times.Therefor every index of array store the last looping value i.e 20